# How do they film animal death scenes?

Tags: film-techniques

When an animal dies in a movie, how do they film it? It's not like they actually kill the animals? Do they just train the animals to lie there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do they prevent animal cruelty in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/how-do-they-prevent-animal-cruelty-in-movies) - the answers seem to cover slaughter as well as harm, and I think the American Humane Association link provided also applies in the case of death.

Comment: @Jenayah But this question is a lot more specific, and is certainly not answered there.

Comment: My understanding is that it's now mostly digital effects, rendering the whole animal, but, in the past, the animals were trained (although cruelty standards, in general, are fairly recent.)

Comment: [This thread](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/how-do-they-make-horses-fall-down-in-war-movies/9719#9719) is a better contender for duplicate, but looks specifically at horses. But I think most of it applies to other animals too - barring the use of CGI and props.

Comment: @Joachim I don't really see how that linked question *doesn't* cover this one. Am I missing something? It asks about preventing hurt and dying animals, like this one.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  This is a question of how they film animal death scenes, the other one about preventing animal cruelty - a matter of filming technique versus prevention. Cruelty is not directly implied here, let alone its prevention. That's why I linked to the other thread, which targets, indirectly, the filming technique of an animal dying (falling).

Comment: Granted. Fortunately we can close it as duplicate of multiple questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson How very fortunate. So the reason for the question being closed is that it's still too broad? I'm slowly trying to understand the intricacies of SE.

Comment: @Joachim No, it's basically covered by already existing questions. Being closed as duplciate doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the question. In fact it's an interesting and on-topic question. It just...has been asked before.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Okay, thanks! I understand the reasoning perfectly, but I still see room for improvement answering this auestion, as the suggested duplicates don't entirely cover this (admittedly very general) question. If I were to ask, say, after the way cinema would portray a cat dying, would that still merit a new question? It's not answered in those threads, and I imagine it's quite different from filming horses. (Apologies for my incessant nitpicking. Last question.)

Comment: @Joachim Don't worry. ;-) It's difficult to say in general. It might very well work. What usually helps is being *aware* of the (possible) duplicates and adressing in the question how your's is different from them, similar to how you do in your comment.